# A friend has stolen item and is it haram to hold something stolen

Tags: theft

I have a friend and he gave me stolen thing to hold on for a while, is it haram to hold it? I don’t do anything else with it

Answer (score 1):

In general any individual involved in a sinful act or assists in a sinful act will be accountable to varying degrees. The primary reason for this is holding onto the item is encouraging the haram behaviour. Refusing it shows that you do not condone such a thing.

Although not exactly your situation, you can read this: https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/82876/ for a little more clarification.

And Allah knows best.